# Changing values of all similar sub arrays in PHP

Tags: php

I've got the following 2D array, stored inside the array variable $my_array

```
Array 
( 
[0] => Array 
       ( 
         [0] => 3 
         [1] => 6 
         [2] => 3 
       ) 
[1] => Array 
       ( 
         [0] => 3 
         [1] => 6 
         [2] => 3 
       ) 
[2] => Array 
       ( 
         [0] => 3 
         [1] => 6 
         [2] => 3 
         ) 
)
```

I wanted to decrement all the [1] sub array values by 3. Tried the following code, with no success.

```
   $my_array[$i]['1']=($my_array[$i]['1'])-3;
   print_r($my_array);
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($my_array as &$val) {
   $val[1] -= 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is what you're after.

```
foreach($my_array as $k=>$v){
  if (isset($my_array[$k][1]) && is_numeric($my_array[$k][1])){
    $my_array[$k][1] -= 3;
  }
}
```